# I don't understand the output of the following Java snippet with break + labels (like goto in other languages)

Tags: java, break

I don't understand the output of the following code:

```
public class testBreak
{

    public static void runTest()
    {
    high_level:
        {
            System.out.println("\nEnter in High Level");
        middle_level: 
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("Enter in Middle level cicle");
                int j = 0;
            low_level:  
                while(j++ < 2)
                {
                    System.out.println("Enter in Low level cicle");
                    System.out.println("i = " + i + ";j = " + j);
                    switch(i)
                    {
                        case 0 : break;
                        case 1 : break low_level;
                        case 2 : break middle_level;
                        case 3 : break high_level;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Exit from Low level cicle");
                }
                System.out.println("Exit from Middle level cicle");
            }
            System.out.println("Exit from High level cicle");
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        runTest();
    }

}
```

Here is the output:

```
Enter in High Level
Enter in Middle level cicle
Enter in Low level cicle
i = 0;j = 1
Exit from Low level cicle
Enter in Low level cicle
i = 0;j = 2
Exit from Low level cicle
Exit from Middle level cicle
Enter in Middle level cicle
Enter in Low level cicle
i = 1;j = 1
Exit from Middle level cicle
Enter in Middle level cicle
Enter in Low level cicle
i = 2;j = 1
Exit from High level cicle
```

I understand up to the line `i = 1;j = 1`
but why does it go to `Exit from Middle level cicle` and not to `Enter in low level cicle` because we have j = 1 and while(j++ < 2) should take 1 < 2, then increase j to 2 and enter the low level cicle as it did in the first run??

editet: It seems break with label does not equal goto, it breaks out of the labeled loop? and the loop is not free in the code like in C/C++, but it is applied to that particular loop?

Comment: Have you already used a debugger?

Comment: @Donat tried the CLI java debugger, but it is clear where the code jumps, was looking for the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `i = 1`, you are telling it to break out of the `low_level` label. The loop below `low_level` stops looping, and then prints `Exit from Middle level cicle`. By doing this, you then loop again below the `middle_level` loop, which is why it then prints `Enter in Middle level cicle`.

Comment: Yeah, I initially understood that break works like a goto statement, not that it jump out of the named loop. if I would have used break high_level it would have jumped out of the { } block referred to by high_level

Comment: Yep, `break high_level;` would just terminate the {} block beneath it, which ends the function in this case. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Java tutorial by Oracle:

> The break statement terminates the labeled statement; it does not
> transfer the flow of control to the label. Control flow is transferred
> to the statement immediately following the labeled (terminated)
> statement.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, I understood it is an exact replacement for goto - seems not.

Comment: This says in essence that it is not an exact replacement for goto. Goto would continue after the label. But it says that it continues *after* the labeled statement.